# How can I add a new child to existing parents in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in Firebase: [image]

Now, I want to add a new node to the children of "rate-comments", call it "0-2-9". In Firebase console I can easily click on the plus sign next to the parent node and add a new child "0-2-9" but this only adds the node under the current parent, and I want that new node to be under all of the parents.

So, how can I automatically add a "0-2-9" node to all of the children of "rate-comments"? I guess this is the equivalent of adding a new column to a table in mysql, which can be easily done in a GUI sql editor. I'm new to Firebase so this may be something obvious.

Comment: No this is not the equivalent of adding a new column in sql. Because you can't have empty nodes in firebase. So if you wat to add the node 0-2-9 you will also have to give it a value.

Comment: I know it's not exactly the equivalent, it was just an observation. I realize that I would need to give them values, but the question still stands - how do I add them all to their parents?

Comment: "how do I add them all to their parents?" It depends on a lot of things. E.g.: Is this to be done from an application? Which kind (web, Android, iOS)? By who (an admin? a regular user?)...

Comment: I'm the admin of the project in Firebase, so yeah it would be by me. I write data to this Firebase database from my php application, but I was wondering if this is possible to do in the Firebase console. But if it isn't I guess I could do it programmatically from my application or some other method.